# Divergence theorem how do you calculate the volume integral, flow?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, gaussian-integral

Hello I really need a thorough answer to one task which is the following one:

Consider the vector field 
$$F(x, y, z) = (xy^2
z, x^2yz, −z),$$  the cylindrical-shape 
Area $$V = \left\{(x, y, z): \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < 5 \text{ and } 0 < z < 4\right\} $$

Now calculate the volume integral ,and calculate:

1. The flow through the surface of the cylinder,
2. The flow through the cover of the cylinder (the area at $z = 4$),
3. The flow through the bottom of the cylinder (the area at $z = 0$)

Sorry for not being accustomed to the formatting here,Im new here since today and I really need this task within the next 11 hours, Im stuck at it and Im not doing well regarding health. for reference it is task A37 on this [link](https://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/schmidfr/Lehre/MRM_WS19/blatt10.pdf) (sorry, it is german.)

I'd be very thankful if you could solve this.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried? Are you sure its $y^z$?

Comment: The volume integral of the divergence, perhaps?

Comment: Ted Shifrin yes

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will work. Here is my answer
[image]

Comment: It's through the surface of cylinder